# textView border radius from right more than left

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
        <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/grey"/>
        <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
            android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
            android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>

        <padding android:bottom="0dip"
            android:left="0dip"
            android:right="0dip"
            android:top="0dip"/>
    </shape>
    </item>
   </layer-list>
```

I am use this code for make border radius its make the textView border radius

I increase the

```
android:topRightRadius="30dp"
android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
```

But it still same like I make

> androd:radius:5dp

my xml

```
 <customfonts.MyTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hello stackoverflow"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:background="@drawable/message"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/fff" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
try this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/grey"/>
    <corners
        android:radius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>

    <padding android:bottom="0dip"
             android:left="0dip"
             android:right="0dip"
             android:top="0dip"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: i add it befor that same

Comment: can you post your layout file?

Comment: same also :/ where did u think the problem ?

Comment: also it may have to do with your custom textview. Replace it with android's TextView and try again

Answer (score 0):

This file is working for me.

I Think for this you don't need **layer-list**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="30dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/red"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="@color/grey"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: then clean your project

Comment: clean rebuild same all border radius like 5dp

Comment: confirm that you are using same layout file as background , and not present it in other folders

Comment: its same when i change color its changed

Comment: then move on @alexmike as your original shape xml  is also working on my layout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114651/discussion-between-n-j-and-alex-mike).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Original TextView]

### Try removing custom TextView and replace it with original TextView

**TextView:**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:text="hello stackoverflow"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@drawable/message"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/fff"
    android:layout_marginLeft="95dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="95dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

**message.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item >
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#ff0000"/>
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#bdbdbd"/>

            <corners android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomRightRadius="30dp" android:topRightRadius="30dp"/>

            <padding android:bottom="0dip"  android:left="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:top="0dip"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```